# How to integrate OAuth sign in using Garmin for react native application?

Tags: node.js, react-native, oauth, garmin

I wish to integrate sign in using fitbit and Garmin, for my react native fitness application.
I found this [Library](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) which looks promising. But however Garmin integration is nowhere to be found. I am very new to this. Can someone guide me on how to proceed or lead me in the right direction?

Comment: HI, @Blake do you find out any solution?